# 50 nodes hadoop passphraseless

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My question is very simple, I want to setup a 50 nodes hadoop cluster, how can I setup the passphraseless between the 50 nodes. if manually operating is very difficult! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to setup SSH between the nodes, it is sufficient to have it **unidirectional** between the master and the slaves. (So only the master must access the slaves without password).

The usual approach is to write a bash script that loops over your slaves file and logs into your slave copying the public key of the master into the authorized keys of the slaves.

[You can see a small workthrough on Praveen Sripati's blog.](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/01/how-to-setup-password-less-ssh-to.html)

However, I'm no admin so I can't tell you if there is a smarter way. Maybe this is better suited on [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/%20Superuser.com)

Comment: do you realize that **loop over your salve files** is easily said than done.

Comment: @FUD the slave file has a hostname entry on each line, a simple `for line in $ (cat conf/slaves) do 'ssh root@$line 'cat .ssh/id_dsa.pub'' >> .ssh/authorized_keys done` is enough (assume you can escape the qoutes correctly then). It's just the time factor of typing 50 times the root password.

Comment: For "between the master and the slaves" make sure you set up communication from the NameNode to the slaves _and_ from the JobTracker to the slaves (assuming the NameNode and JobTracker processes are running on separate machines). The various `bin/hadoop-daemons.sh` invocations use those SSH keys when restarting name- or job-based processes across the slaves, _en masse_.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

> To work seamlessly, SSH needs to be set up to allow password-less
> login for the hadoop user from machines in the cluster. The simplest
> way to achieve this is to generate a public/private key pair, and
> place it in an NFS location that is shared across the cluster.
>
> First,
> generate an RSA key pair by typing the following in the hadoop user
> account:
>
> % ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> Even though we want
> password-less logins, keys without passphrases are not considered good
> practice (it’s OK to have an empty passphrase when running a local
> pseudodistributed cluster, as described in Appendix A), so we specify
> a passphrase when prompted for one. We shall use ssh-agent to avoid
> the need to enter a password for each connection.
>
> The private key is
> in the file specified by the -f option, ~/.ssh/id_rsa, and the public
> key is stored in a file with the same name with .pub appended,
> ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
>
> Next we need to make sure that the public key is in
> the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on all the machines in the cluster
> that we want to connect to. If the hadoop user’s home directory is an
> NFS filesystem, as described earlier, then the keys can be shared
> across the cluster by typing:
>
> % cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >>
> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
>
> If the home directory is not shared using NFS,
> then the public keys will need to be shared by some other means.
>
> Test
> that you can SSH from the master to a worker machine by making sure
> sshagent is running,3 and then run ssh-add to store your passphrase.
> You should be able to ssh to a worker without entering the passphrase
> again.

Source:
Tom White, Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, page 301

Found it googling here:
https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=22&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjABOBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbigdata.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FOreilly.Hadoop.The.Definitive.Guide.3rd.Edition.Jan.2012.pdf&ei=sGzZULb6OfOM0wWhlYDYAw&usg=AFQjCNGvNUZcQBvM_Ucqf_K0JGAlCRxr3A&sig2=Qpa_KZyP1mXXm9yQv0ynRw&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k